# @Builder.Default doesn't work in constructor range

Tags: lombok, builder

I'm testing BuilderExample. I put @Builder annotation in constructor.
I expected list = [] and num = 5;

But it doesn't work in constructor level. It wokrs in the class level.
It seems it supposed to be worked too in constructor level.

```
 @Data
public class BuilderExample {

    @Builder.Default
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    private String test1;
    private String test;

    @Builder.Default
    private int num = 5;

    @Builder
    private BuilderExample(List<Integer> list, String test1, String test, int num) { 
        this.list = list;
        this.test1 = test1;
        this.test = test;
        this.num = num;
    }
 }
```

"""

```
class BuilderTestExample {

    @Test
    void test() {
        BuilderExample b = BuilderExample.builder().test("Test").build();

        Assertions.assertEquals(b.getTest(), "Test");
        Assertions.assertEquals(b.getTest1(), null);
        Assertions.assertEquals(b.getNum(), 5);
        Assertions.assertEquals(b.getList(), new ArrayList<>());
    }

}
```

"""

Answer (score 0):

`@Builder.Default` does not work if you put `@Builder` on a method or a constructor.
The [lombok documentation also mentions this](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder#builderdefault):

> If you've put @Builder on a class (and not a method or constructor) you can instead specify the default directly on the field [...].

The reason is that it is not always possible to determine a mapping between the parameter and the field, as those might have different names, or there may be more complex code to fill the value of a field than just a simple assignment.

If you want `@Builder.Default`, use a class-level `@Builder`.

Comment: If i want to keep the Builder in constructor, should I exclude the fields which need default value? or is it better to make putting value when creating the entity with NotNull annotation?

Comment: That depends on your use case. Do you need the fields to be settable by the builder? Then excluding them is not an option. If `0` or `null` is not a valid value, you could also simply assign the default value in the constructor.